# Custom cuts using R and `choropleth` in package `GISTools`

Tags: shapefile, r, choropleth

I am plotting some data on a shapefile using R and `choropleth` in package`GISTools`
I would like to modify my code below in order to assign custom breaks.

Using the World Borders Dataset, download from: `http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.zip`

```
library(GISTools)
library(rgdal)

shape_file <- readOGR(dsn ="/home/hamid/TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3",
                      layer = "TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3")

shades <- auto.shading(shape_file@data$POP2005, cutter = quantileCuts, 
                       n=5, cols = brewer.pal(5, "Blues"))
choropleth(shape_file, shape_file@data$POP2005,
           shading = shades)                      
choro.legend(70.00000, 32.50000, shades)
```

Can anyone help please?

UPDATE

No errors in the code I have posted. What I would like to do is to use custom cuts instead of quantile cuts.
I have trie the following:

```
cuts= c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.6)
shades <- shading(shape_file@data$POP2005, breaks = cuts)
choropleth(shape_file, shape_file@data$POP2005, shading = shades)
```

which give the following error:

```
Error in findInterval(v, shading$breaks) : 
vec' must be sorted non-decreasingly`
```

Note that the values for the breaks are specific to my case which is not using the same data on the example.

Comment: Can you specify the problem? any error message?

Comment: I update the post.

Comment: I have used your code on my machine and I get no error. Can you make a simple reproducible example of your error?

Comment: Can you post the result of `shades$breaks` ?

Comment: the problem is that I am using data which I cannot share.
Actually I have one shapefile and dataframe, I am plotting the data from the df on the shape file. Of course each polygon is identified in df by the same ID assign to the correspondin polygon in the shapefile.
So I don't understand why  the code I have wrote does not work.

Comment: I can't really help you without a reproducible error. The code you provided above, works. Basically the error say that you must use breaks that are sorted non-decreasingly. Namely `cuts <- c(1, 2, 3)` is good and `cuts <- c(3, 2, 1)` is no good.